# Ubuntu freezes after restart after install on old MacbookPro

Tags: boot, system-installation, screen, freeze, macbook

Im trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a 2008 Macbook Pro. I can get through adding "nomodeset", selecting install ubuntu and the "install third party software" option, selecting the "encrypt" option, setting up and encryption key, setting up a profile, getting the "installation complete, please restart" prompt, restarting, and the "please remove the installation medium then press ENTER" prompt. I pull the flashdrive out and press ENTER.  The computer restarts, does the classic apple *BONG*, asks for encryt password, I enter password, get the spinning ring on the UBUNTU screen, the spinning ring goes away, then it goes to the purple screen and sits there indefinitely. I can move my mouse aroudn the screen but cant do anything else. I've tried every option I can find on the internet and probably reinstalled about 3 dozen times. Anyone have any ideas?